# Default value for flags enum in a RESTful WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, enums

WCF supports using enum types that are tagged with the `FlagsAttribute` as parameters within an `UriTemplate`. Like this:

```cs
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum OptionsEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    None = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption1 = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption2 = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption3 = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption4 = 8
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface MyServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "resource?options={options}")]
    void MyOperation(OptionsEnum options);
}
```

The resource can then be requested via URLs like this:

`GET /resource?options=None`

`GET /resource?options=MyOption1`

`GET /resource?options=MyOption1,MyOption3`

All of this works really nicely as long the URL actually contains a value for the `options` parameter. However, if I request the resource without specifying a value in the URL, like this:

`GET /resource`

I get an exception with the message **Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value**
and the following stack trace:

```
at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.QueryStringConverter.ConvertStringToValue(String parameter, Type parameterType)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Obviously, this is because `QueryStringConverter` passes `null` into `Enum.Parse(...)` in this case. As a result the implementation of `MyServiceContract` will not be executed.

Of course I could just switch to `string` for the type of the `options` parameter and do all the parsing stuff myself within the service implementation, but that's not what I want, really.

Does anyone know a clean solution to have `OptionsEnum.None` passed into the service implementation if the URL does not contain a value (just like `0` is passed for omitted parameters of type `int`)?

I already tried using a custom `TypeConverter` implementation, but even that does not seem to work. Looking at the implementation of `QueryStringConverter` it seems like it will always try to convert `enum` types by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution that is reusable and does not involve switching to `string` for the type of the flags parameter. I was hoping for something simpler, though. Anyway, in case it helps someone else, here it is.

The approach is relatively simple:

- Wrap the enum in a reference type.
- Use a `TypeConverter` to customize the process of converting the value from `string` to our flags enum as implemented by WCF's `QueryStringConverter`.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Wraps a flags enum value.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class is meant to be used in conjunction with 
/// <see cref="FlagsConverter{TFlags,TEnum}"/> and simply boxes an enum.
/// This is necessary in order to customize WCF's default behavior for enum
/// types (as implemented by <see cref="QueryStringConverter"/>) by using a
/// <see cref="TypeConverter"/>.
/// </remarks>
/// <devdoc>
/// We prefer this over using an 1-Tuple (<see cref="Tuple{T1} "/>) as it
/// allows us to add constraints on the type parameter. Also, the value 
/// wrapped by a <see cref="Tuple{T1} "/> is read-only, which we don't want
/// here, as there is no reason to prevent [OperationContract] methods from
/// writing the wrapped <see cref="Value"/>.
/// </devdoc>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">
/// The enum type. Must be attributed with <see cref="FlagsAttribute"/>.
/// </typeparam>
public abstract class Flags<TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    // Use a static c'tor to add run-time checks on the type parameter that
    // cannot be checked at compile-time via constraints.
    static Flags()
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("T is not an enum");
        }

        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("T is not a flags enum");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The enum value.
    /// </summary>
    public TEnum Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="TypeConverter"/> implementation that converts from
/// <c>string</c> to <see cref="Flags{TEnum}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// Meant to be used in conjunction with <see cref="Flags{TEnum}"/>.
/// The purpose of this <see cref="TypeConverter"/> implementation is to
/// convert both <c>null</c> and the empty string to <c>default(TEnum)</c>
/// instead of throwing an exception. This way, a flags enum (wrapped in an
/// instance of <see cref="Flags{TEnum}"/>) can be used as the type of an
/// optional parameter in a RESTful WCF <c>OperationContract</c> method.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// If the string value (as provided by <see cref="QueryStringConverter"/>)
/// is <c>null</c> or empty or can be successfully parsed into an enum 
/// value of type <typeparamref name="TEnum"/>, this implementation will
/// provide an instance of <typeparamref name="TFlags"/>. Thus, there is no
/// need to check a <typeparamref name="TFlags"/>-typed value for 
/// <c>null</c> within the implementation of an <c>OperationContract</c>
/// method.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="TFlags">
/// A sub-class of <see cref="Flags{TEnum}"/>. Must have a default c'tor.
/// </typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">
/// The enum type. Must be attributed with <see cref="FlagsAttribute"/>.
/// </typeparam>
public class FlagsConverter<TFlags, TEnum> : TypeConverter
    where TFlags : Flags<TEnum>, new()
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            // The following line is what Flags<> and FlagsConverter<,> is
            // all about: Provide the enum's default value (meaning no flag
            // is set) for null and the empty string instead of passing it
            // into Enum.Parse() (which results in an ArgumentException).
            return new TFlags { Value = default(TEnum) };
        }

        // Otherwise, just pass the value on the Enum.Parse(), i.e. don't 
        // add any further changes to WCF's default behavior as implemented
        // by QueryStringConverter.
        return new TFlags { Value = (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), (string)value, true) };
    }
}
```

These two classes can now be used to solve the problem like this 
(reusing the example from the original question):

```cs
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum OptionsEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    None = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption1 = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption2 = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption3 = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    MyOption4 = 8
}

[DataContract]
[TypeConverter(typeof(FlagsConverter<MyOptionalFlags, OptionsEnum>))]
public class MyOptionalFlags
    : Flags<OptionsEnum>
{
    // We don't add anything here, as the whole purpose of this class is to
    // wrap the OptionsEnum in a class that will be instantiated by the
    // attributed FlagsConverter.
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface MyServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "resource?options={options}")]
    void MyOperation(MyOptionalFlags options);
}

public class MyServiceContractImpl
    : MyServiceContract
{
    public void MyOperation(MyOptionalFlags options)
    {
        if (options.Value == OptionsEnum.None)
        {
            // We will now get here for requests that do not specify a 
            // value for the options parameter in the URL. Note that just 
            // like for an enum value, we don't have to check if options is
            // null here.
        }
    }
}
```